# What is the proper way to do the strong and em elements together?

Tags: html

I keep "getting end tag for element "EM" which is not open
end tag for element "STRONG" which is not open" in the validator and I can't seem to figure out how to implement this correctly.

I have tried moving around the tags, also I have checked and there is 1 opening and 1 closing of each so I am a tad bid confused. Line 34 & 35.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<head>
<title>  Restaurant Information </title>
<style type="text/css">

    p{font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman",
    Times, serif;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    color: #333333;
    line-height: 20px;}
    h1{font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman",
    Times, serif;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    color: #000033;}
    h2{font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman",
    Times, serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #000033;}
    h3{font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman",
    Times, serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #000033;}
    .boldit {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #990000;
    letter-spacing: .1em;}
    .style1 {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000066; }
    a:link {color: #006666; }
    a:visited{color: #FF6633; }
    <strong><em>stuff typed </em> </strong>
    strong em {font-size: .9em 
    color: #336666;}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Restaurant Information</h1>

<!-- Resturant infomation section -->
<p> <span class="boldit">TYPE OF CUISINE:</span> Italian and Continental</p>
<p><span class ="boldit">PRICE RANGE:</span> Lunch Entrees $9 to $14, Dinner $12 to $21</p>
<p><span class = "boldit">ATMOSPHERE:</span> Elegant but casual, Cozy, Romantic, Fun & Festive, Like your second home.</p>
<p><span class="boldit">APPEALS TO:</span> Appeals to everyone, from Tourists to Couples and especially to Business Groups</p>
<p><span class = "boldit">DRESS CODE:</span> Elegant but casual</p>
<p><span class = "boldit">MEALS SERVED:</span> Lunch, Dinner</p>

<!-- END OF RESTURANT INFO -->

<!-- START OF CONTACT US -->
<h3>Contact Us:
</h3>
<br>                      
</br>
<p><span class = "boldit"> ADDRESS:</span> </p>
<p class = "style1"> Cafe Townsend </p>
<p class = "style1"> 600 Townsend </p>
<p class = "style1"> San Francisco, CA 94103 </p>
<p>
<span class ="boldit">PHONE: (415) 555-1234</span>
</p>
<p>
<span class = "boldit">FAX: (415) 555-1235</span>
</p>
<p><a href = "mailto: info@cafetownsend.com">Email Us</a> </p>
<p>
<span class = "boldit">DIRECTIONS:</span> Directions Via <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/600+Townsend+St,+San+Francisco,+CA+94103/@37.771696,-122.4047585,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x808f7e2cbdae8fcf:0xb43116e96526b6df!8m2!3d37.771696!4d-122.4025698?hl=en">Link to Google Map</a>. </p>
<p>
<span class = "boldit">HOURS:</span> Cafe Townsend is open seven days a week for dinner and Monday thru Friday for lunch.</p> 
<p>
<span class = "boldit"> LUNCH: </span> Monday thru Friday 11:30am - 2:00pm </p>
<p><span class = "boldit">DINNER:</span>Sunday thru Thursday 5:30pm - 10:00pm</p>
<p>Friday and Saturday 5:30pm - 11:00pm</p>

<p><span class = "boldit">CREDIT CARDS ACCEPTED:</span> Visa, Mastercard, American Express, Discover, Diners Club</p>

<!-- END OF RESTURANT INFO -->

<!-- START OF AWARDS AND RECONIZATION -->


<h2>Awards and Recognition: </h2>

<p>Best New Restaurant <br>
<strong><em>Restaurant News, 1994</strong></em></p>
</br>
<p>Best Veal in California <br>
<strong><em>California Magazine, February 2002</strong></em>
<p><span class = "boldit">SPECIAL FEATURE:</span> Cafe Townsend serves only the very highest quality meats, authentically prepared for your dining pleasure. A specialty at Cafe Townsend is the signature dishes that are presented tableside. Dine in our elegantly casual atmosphere at our convenient San Francisco location.</p>



<!-- END OF AWARDS -->


<!-- START OF CAFE TOWNSEND IS PROUD.... -->

<h2>Cafe Townsend Is Proud To Offer The Following Services:</h2>

<p><span class = "boldit">BANQUET FACILITIES / PRIVATE ROOM:</span> We can accommodate your party of up to 34 (50 for standing receptions) in our private dining room with Roman motif and gold and peach accents. This room offers soundproof doors and lighting that will adjust from candlelight to reading luminance. In addition, we have semi-private accommodations, seating up to 50, in one section of our main dining room that can be separated by curtains. For groups of 100 to 120 our main dining room is available. Cafe Townsend will also consider closing the restaurant for a minimum charge to provide the space you need to accommodate your largest parties. <a href="specialevents.html">Read about our Special Events</a>.</p>

<p><span class = "boldit">BAR:</span> Cafe Townsend offers a full service bar. In addition, we have three frozen specialty drinks. For a special occasion, try the Belini, a combination of peach nectar, champagne and Bacardi.</p>

<p><span class = "boldit">CATERING:</span> Both on and off premise catering is available. See the Special Events page for more details.</p>

<p><span class = "boldit">DELIVERY / TAKE-OUT:</span> Our full menu is available for take-out. Cafe Townsend does not offer delivery.</p>

<p><span class = "boldit">ENTERTAINMENT:</span> Enjoy our new red Digital Surround Sound Baby Grand Concert Master "Digital" Piano.</p>

<p><span class = "boldit">RESERVATIONS:</span> Recommended</p>

<p><span class = "boldit">SEATING CAPACITY:</span> 200</p>

<p><span class = "boldit">SMOKING CHOICE:</span> Our restaurant is proud to be a non-smoking establishment.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi there. You have the `<strong>` and `<em>` HTML tags in your CSS style section, where they don’t mean anything.

Comment: Also, these tags are semantic, they refer to the structure of the text to identify important parts of it. You can also completely control the style just from CSS by using a class within those tags, for example.

Answer (score 0):

HTML tags are not valid inside a STYLE block (as Chris hints in his comment). The text content inside the STYLE tags **must** be CSS, not HTML, which is why the HTML validator does not like it. (When used in this way the STYLE element is effectively a way of embedding a style sheet directly in the HTML.)

The validator is not really telling you that directly though -- and it could certainly be giving us a more helpful error message in this instance.

The validator is complaining about this:

```
Line 34, Column 33: end tag for element "EM" which is not open
    <strong><em>stuff typed </em> </strong>
```

because (I assume) it did not parse the opening EM tag on the very same line, because it was not expecting it to be there, because it is in a STYLE block and therefore should not be HTML content.

However a subsequent validator rule *did* parse the closing tag and so the error is thrown. A more useful error message would be "HTML elements are not valid children of a STYLE element".

But, because of your DOCTYPE:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

...you are checking against a very old version of the validation rules, and therefore probably an old version of the validator. You probably should be using an HTML5 doctype like this instead:

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

And with that DOCTYPE, you get a much more useful error message:

```
Error: CSS: Parse Error.

From line 35, column 21; to line 36, column 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple issues with your CSS.

You have HTML in your CSS, remove `<strong><em>stuff typed </em> </strong>`.  You are also missing a semicolon after `strong em {font-size: .9em`.

Replace your CSS with the below.

```
<style type="text/css">
    p{
        font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman",
        Times, serif;
        font-size: 0.95em;
        color: #333333;
        line-height: 20px;
    }

    h1{
        font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman",
        Times, serif;
        font-size: 1.4em;
        color: #000033;
    }

    h2{
        font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman",
        Times, serif;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        color: #000033;
    }

    h3{
        font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman",
        Times, serif;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        color: #000033;
    }

    .boldit {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 0.95em;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #990000;
        letter-spacing: .1em;
    }

    .style1 {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #000066; 
    }

    a:link {color: #006666; }
    a:visited{color: #FF6633; }

    strong {

    }

    strong em {
        font-size: .9em;
        color: #336666;
    }
</style>
```